# Do-While Loop in Robot Framework using Selenium

Tags: robotframework

I need to test the Load More button using **`Do-While Loop`** in Robot Framework using Selenium. I don't know the syntax of `do-while` so I used a common syntax in the following code.

My Sample Code Logic

```
do {

    Run Keyword If    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   ${PO_FieldLabel}) == FALSE     FAIL Item not loaded Properly

} while (Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   ${PO_LoadMore_Btn})
```

My logic is to loop the iteration till the Load More Button `${PO_LoadMore_Btn}` is exist. If exist, check the Name Field `${PO_FieldLabel}` is exist. Once the Name Field `${PO_FieldLabel}` is NOT EXIST, **`FAIL`** the test case and skip the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Robot Framework, there is **NO** `WHILE LOOP`, `DO-WHILE LOOP`. It has only `FOR LOOP` We can perform the `DO-WHILE LOOP` using `FOR LOOP`

Kindly look the following code

```
:FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    999999
/
/     YOUR LOGIC
/
/    Exit For Loop If    {bool expression}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Robot Framework looping is done using the `:FOR` loop construction. The Robot Framework [userguide section on Loops](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops) has more information on the types of loops you can construct and the input they require.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

While loops have been added to RobotFramework 5.0

This allows you to build a DO-While structure with in infinite While loop you conditionally break.

```
WHILE    True
    
    # Body of your Do-While loop here
    
    IF    ${some_condition}
        BREAK
    END
END
```

Documentation: [v5.0](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/5.0/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#while-loops) [Latest](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#while-loops)